# How to change default background colour in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have all my labels and buttons to have a white background.
I know I can use `bg="white"` in each one but I was thinking if there was a way I could change the default colour to white or make it so that all widgets have a white background with a single line of code. similar to how you can change the font by doing:

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.option_add("*font",("Arial",15))
window.mainloop()
```

Which will set all the font to Arial 15

Comment: Did you try `window.option_add("*Label*Background", "white")` and `window.option_add("*Button*Background", "white")`?

Comment: @acw1668 I didn't, just tried it and it worked, tysm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to @acw1668 's comment, can do
`window.option_add("*Label*Background", "white")`
and
`window.option_add("*Button*Background", "white")`
to solve it. Just thought id put it as an answer in case people don't see the comment and what not.

Comment: You can also configure the background for everything with the single statement `root.option_add("*Background", "white")`.  You don't have to do each widget class individually.

Comment: @BryanOakley Great, This helped! Is there any way to add exceptions? Like All backgrounds except buttons?

Comment: @SushantPawar: no, there isn't a syntax for everything except a class.

Comment: @BryanOakley Apart from *Background, *Font, *tearOff What are other options do we have? I tried to find I only found these. If possible please share a link to documentation.

Comment: @SushantPawar: a good tutorial on the tk option database can be found at the following link. It is written from the perspective of tcl/tk rather than python/tkinter, but all of the concepts are the same since tkinter is just a wrapper around tcl/tk. See [Options and Tk - A Beginner's Guide](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~fellowsd/tcl/option-tutorial.html)